# Console Application with Spring 3 and log4J

Tags: eclipse, spring, log4j

I'm trying to init log4J with Spring and make log4j a little less talkative. But I fail to shut spring down in logging.

I've put this in my spring.xml:

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>properties/log4j.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my log4J.properties:

```
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.com.app=DEBUG, FileAppender

log4J.logger.org.springframework=INFO, stdout
# Skipped all appenders definition.
```

I got a spring helper class:

```
public class AppContext
{

private static ApplicationContext ctx;

public static void init()
{
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "file:properties/ApplicationContext.xml");
}
// Snipped the rest.
}
```

When I start my app, I get this:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I thought that the static bean was created and called the Log4jConfigurer, but no.

I run from my eclipse, this runConfig as this:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:properties/log4j.properties
```

What did I miss?

---

Thanks for your input, here are new elements:

@Hellectronic you mean that ClassPathXmlApplicationContext is not able to use log4j?

@Ralph I mean this:

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>properties/log4j.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Ok, to sum it up : 
I must uncomment the lo4j.rootLogger to enable him to configure.
Remove the std or FileAppender after my dedicated loggers to avoid the double log entry.

Comment: The log variable in `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is from commons logger

Comment: What do you mean by: "I've put this in my spring.xml : properties/log4j.properties"?

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * 初始化Spring环境, 并初始化采集任务
 */
private void setup() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Console程序必须使用Spring Log4jConfigurer 初始化Log4j
    Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Env.getLog4jConfig());
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(DEFAULT_APPLICATION_CONTEXT);
    SpringContextHolder contextHolder = new SpringContextHolder();
    contextHolder.setApplicationContext(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not picking up your log4j config; the request solution is to put it in the classpath and let log4j find it itself.

Also make sure your run configuration is using a startup directory from which the path configuration you specify makes sense, or supply an absolute path.

Comment: In fact it does pick it up : it is specified by Eclipse in the program arguments. The pb was elsewhere  : I had commented out this line : log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout in my log4j.properties. Now it works but it logs twice :( 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO, stdout

Comment: @charly's Remove the `stdout` from the Spring logger definition?

Comment: @charly's Also, did you even notice that not all of your question was showing up? Because you didn't indent the commented-out rootLogger line, it showed up normally on my mobile device; on the site it was a markdown header. The XML didn't show up at all. Proofread.

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.logger.COMM.aPP=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO